# Can I use a segmented abrasive blade in my circular saw for cutting drywall?

Tags: saw

Is it o.k. to substitute a 41/2" dia. segmented cutting wheel in my 43/8" dia. 14.4V saw? No one makes blades anymore, since B&D/dewalt abandoned
the line.

I use my saw to cut drywall, and install the blocking for the cabinets that the carpenters 'forgot'. Or do I need one of those 'diamond-encrusted' blades?

Comment: Please ask one question per post. I've removed the dust question. Feel free to post another question.

Comment: Just get an oscillating saw, it cuts drywall like butter.

Answer (score 2):

You ask if a 4-1/2" blade will fit a 4-3/8 saw probably not, but take the saw to the store and ask them to let you see if it will fit.
Using a saw to cut drywall? I usually use a razor knife, or a jab saw when cutting in old work boxes, I have never seen someone use a circular saw to cut drywall, I would hate to see the mess that leaves. Change over to a razor knife if you want less mess.

Comment: Why don't you think it would fit? 1/16" in radius increase is probably within the normal variation for those blades from different makers anyway.

Comment: Having tried to fit a different size blade for a mikata battery circular saw there was not enough clearance, so I doubt it would fit but with no other options I did suggest to take it to the store and try.

Comment: I saw someone cut drywall with a circular saw one, and it was a huge mess.  They were replacing all the plumbing in a large house, so they had a lot of drywall to cut.  In that case, I think it made sense.  They started the project with a brand new shop vac connected to the saw for dust collection.  They threw the vacuum away at the end of the project.  They also sealed off each room they worked in with plastic sheeting because the vacuum couldn't catch it all. I suggest sticking with a jab saw or maybe an oscillating cutting tool.

Comment: @isherwood even if it fits, I would never gamble with a saw.  Only use it as intended.

Comment: @QuocVu, you're kidding, right? The size difference is negligible at best. My money says they're the exact same thing marketed with different numbers for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, abrasive wheels don't work well for soft materials. They'll probably cut drywall slowly and may result in burning. They won't touch wood.

It seems to me that **[blades are readily available](https://www.google.com/search?q=4-3%2F8%22%20saw%20blade&oq=4-3%2F8%22%20saw%20blade&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0l4.4473j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8https://www.google.com/search?q=4-3%2F8%22%20saw%20blade&oq=4-3%2F8%22%20saw%20blade&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0l4.4473j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)** in that size, though.

Answer (score -1):

I know the question is about powertools, but the goal is cutting drywall:  The fastest & easiest way to cut drywall is just score it with a knife and then 'snap' it along that line (like cutting glass).  All the strength of the drywall is in the paper, and if you score the paper deeply the whole sheet snaps along that line easy as can be.

Comment: I think OP is cutting existing walls.  Not new drywall.

Comment: keyhole saw, or sabre saw then, not something with spinning blade and lots of wind!